# Points on surface where tangent plane is parallel to given plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

There are many questions like this, but none of them expose my error.

Given the surface:
$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{256}+\frac{z^2}{2304}=1$$

Find the points where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $2x-3y+z=5$.

I found the gradient of the surface: $\left\langle \frac {2x}{9}, \frac{2y}{256}, \frac{2z}{2304} \right\rangle$

I found the normal to the plane: $\langle 2,-3,1 \rangle$

I solved for $(a,b,c)$ with:

$$\left\langle \frac {2x}{9}, \frac{2y}{256}, \frac{2z}{2304} \right\rangle=\langle 2,-3,1 \rangle$$

I determined the point to be $(9,-384,1152)$. This is apparently wrong, though I see no arithmetical or algebraic errors. I also tried the *antiparallel* point $(-9,384,-1152)$, which does not even seem like a correct notion. Are there more points?

I would appreciate any help as to what corrections I need to make.

Comment: $\left\langle \frac {2x}{9},\;\frac{2y}{256}, \;\frac{2z}{2304} \right\rangle= \lambda \langle 2,-3,1 \rangle$  for real unknown $\lambda$  You then get the value(s)   of $\lambda$  by plugging back into  $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{256}+\frac{z^2}{2304}=1$

Comment: @WillJagy That solved my issue. Thank you so much. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out. A careless typo. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @WillJagy for answering in the comments. I am answering this to close the question.

Let $\left\langle \frac {2x}{9}, \frac{2y}{256}, \frac{2z}{2304} \right\rangle= \lambda ⟨2,−3,1⟩$

Instead of a point $(a,b,c)$, this results in $P: (\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$.

Plug $P$ back into the surface $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{256}+\frac{z^2}{2304}=1$ and solve for the value(s) of $\lambda$. Plug the resulting value(s) for $\lambda$ back into  $P: (\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$ for the points.